# Move react components before / after each other on a page (sorting)

Tags: javascript, dom, reactjs

I have react components following each other in a manner similar to this:

```
<MyComponent position="1" />
<MyComponent position="2" />
<MyComponent position="3" />
<MyComponent position="4" />
<MyComponent position="5" />
```

(There can be variable amount of components) with following render template related to them

```
<div data-position={this.props.position}>
  <span className="move-up" onClick={this.moveUp}>^</span>
  <span className="move-down" onClick={this.moveDown}>v</span>
</div>
```

both `moveUp` and `moveDown` functions are empty at the moment. I am trying to figure out correct react approach to move component below or above its neighbor depending on which span was clicked (move-up or move-down). Once move is done I also need to update position props respectively.

Example of this can be someone clicks move-down on MyComponent with position 2, it moves it down to position 3 and component that previously had position 3 now becomes position 2, this is vice versa if component is moved up.

Comment: Have you tried flexboxes yet?

Comment: does the syntax onClick="this.moveUp" works? shouldn't be like onClick={this.moveUp}

Comment: @Vikramaditya was a typo, fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to put all your `<MyComponent />` in an array and on moveUp and moveDown Action swap the content of your array.

```
let arr = []; // make it a state variable
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
     arr.push( <MyComponent key = {i} moveUp = {this.moveUp.bind(this)}   moveDown = {this.moveDown.bind(this)} position = {i}/>)
}
this.setState({arr : arr});
```

and on the moveUp/Down action

```
moveUp(index){
  let arr = this.state.arr;
  // SWAP array content
  let tmp = arr[index];
  arr[index] = arr[index + 1]; // put more conditions to handle edge cases
  arr[index + 1] = tmp;
  this.setState({arr: arr});
}
```

Comment: There is a issue with this approach in my case, as I don't know if there will be exactly 5 items, there could be more or less (users keep adding and removing items)

Comment: in that case, you have to keep track of your array length, and test case will apply for the first and last elements on the array.

Answer (score 0):

Just use flexbox. You can use it with React-native and browsers. It's so much easier than moving stuff in array and keeping arrays in order. With flexbox you can use arrays, you can use objects and don't care about order issues in JavaScript.

This is my favorite flexbox guide: 
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

In short, add div around your items and set it's styles:

```
display: flex;
```

For children add

```
order: X;
```

Order is just any number. Default is 0.

You can read more about this prop here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order

With flexbox you will support IE10+ and real browsers: Chrome, FF, Safari. http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox

Knowing, that windows are not supporting IE10 and any older IE and alerting IE users about this, it's already safe to stop supporting those old craps. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/WindowsForBusiness/End-of-IE-support

Comment: Will this also render html in correct order? I looked into this, but it is just visually representing it in correct order, however html structure remains the same.